# What's absolute unique visitors in Google Analytics regarding my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, google-analytics

I have an iPhone app connected with Google analytics. The mistery comes when checking absolute unique visitors in the https://www.google.com/analytics. It is not the different visitors have played with my app as I expected, cause it shows a much higher number than we are in our development team. So,
What's absolute unique visitors in Google Analytics regarding my iPhone app?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolute unique visitors are tracked using a cookie sent to the client. If your client is unable to accept the cookie (as is probably the case with a native iPhone app) then the client will be counted each time it hits the analytics code. What you're probably seeing is a count of every use of the app.

http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33087

Comment: Thanks for your promt response. Actually, total visits are 172 now and unique visitors 36 ... If it helps, it may worth saying that other cookies (as social netwoks) are well aceptted in the app. Maybe it filters among cookies ... I will check printing the cookies.

Comment: Well ... Thinking about your response gives me the answer. Actually we remove the app from the devices several times for test purposes... I guess it also deletes the cookies, counting new visitors when not desired. You have the accepted answer!

Comment: I've seen similar things happen when testing web apps on certain mobile devices. Glad to hear the mystery is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it's becuase in Google Analytics unique visitors != unique users.

As I understand it, Unique Visitors are measured per session and not by using a persisted unique user id on the device.

This means that:

- If the same user uses the application in 09:01 and again in 09:15 - it's still the same session (session timeuot is 30 min as far as I know) and the user is counted one unique visitor.
- But, if the same user uses the application in 09:01 and again in 11:15 - it's a whole new session and the same user is counted as 2 differnt unique visitor (=> users!=visitor).